# In Neo4j (4.1.3), how can I do a match against 3 nodes one after another if a node does not exist

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 nodes Employees, Contractors. I need to get id for a name first in Employees, if not found then in Contractors and still not found get id for a default name. I have below so far and I do not have the correct IF systax.

```
WITH row WHERE row.CREATED_BY is not null and row.CREATED_BY <> 'None'
  CALL apoc.when(row.CREATED_BY_NTID IS NOT NULL,
          "MATCH (p:Employee {name: row.CREATED_BY}) WHERE p.account ENDS WITH row.CREATED_BY_NTID return p",
          "MATCH (p:Employee {name: row.CREATED_BY}) return p",
          {row:row}) yield value
With row, value.p as p
  IF value.p IS null
    CALL apoc.when(row.CREATED_BY_NTID IS NOT NULL,
          "MATCH (p:Contractor {name: row.CREATED_BY}) WHERE p.account ENDS WITH row.CREATED_BY_NTID return p",
          "MATCH (p:Contractor {name: row.CREATED_BY}) return p",
          {row:row}) yield value
With row, value.p as p
  IF value.p IS null
        match (p:Employee) where p.name starts with 'XXXXXXX' return p
```

Comment: Are you using the neo4j 4.x?

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.1.3 - also edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add multiple conditions within apoc.when (for some reason when I posted it did not work maybe I had some other problem).

```
WITH row 
  CALL apoc.when(row.CREATED_BY_NTID IS NOT NULL,
          "MATCH (p:Employee {name: row.CREATED_BY}) WHERE p.account ENDS WITH row.CREATED_BY_NTID return p",
          "MATCH (p:Employee {name: row.CREATED_BY}) return p",
          {row:row}) yield value
With row, value.p as p
    CALL apoc.when(row.CREATED_BY_NTID IS NOT NULL AND p is NULL,
          "MATCH (p:Contractor {name: row.CREATED_BY}) WHERE p.account ENDS WITH row.CREATED_BY_NTID return p",
          "MATCH (p:Contractor {name: row.CREATED_BY}) return p",
          {row:row}) yield value
With row, value.p as p
CALL apoc.when(p is NULL,
        "match (p:Employee) where p.name starts with 'XXXXXXX' return p", "", {row:row}) yield value
....
```